# Python Pandas. replace incorrect dates in a column with default when converting

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a date column to `datetime64[ns]` and I am using the following line

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype('datetime64[ns]',errors="ignore")
```

If I don't use `ignore` key, the script crashes at this line.

Now some of the values in this column are incorrect and they may nor may not be date at all.
How do I convert all the date values to the date format and replace all non date values to

Edit: The `coerce` doesn't work anymore as per the compiler, only options are `raise` and `ignore`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` and then replace missing values:

```
datetime = '2000-01-01'
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors='coerce').fillna(pd.Timestamp(datetime))
```

If possible missing values in column and need not convert them:

```
datetime = '2000-01-01'
m = df["Date"].notna()
df.loc[m, "Date"] = (pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m, "Date"], errors='coerce')
                       .fillna(pd.Timestamp(datetime)))
```

Comment: will this account for string or improper/incorrect date format like "2222-22-22"?

Comment: I don't think the `coerce` tag works anymore after the update, Only options are 'raise' or 'ignore'

Comment: @PrashantKumar - sure, it will be NaT and then `datetime`

Comment: @PrashantKumar - I dont use `astype`, but `to_datetime`